# joomla 3.0 extension manager not finding update of module

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions, joomla3.0

I developed a module that can be updated in Joomla 2.5 Extension Manager.
I can't find information anywhere that indicates that something needs to be different in order to work properly in Joomla 3.0

I don't intend to advertise this module by providing the link to it, I'm just trying to find help to fix this problem.
Here is the page where you can download it:
http://code.google.com/p/mod-random-article/downloads/list

If you install v1.1 on Joomla 2.5, the Extension Manager will find the new update v1.2.
If you install it on Joomla 3.0, the Extension Manager won't find the new version.

Can anyone help?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution for my problem.
This looks so easy.. I don't know how I couldn't find this earlier.

I had to add another  tag to the manifest file on the update server targeting Joomla 3.0, like this:

```
<updates>  
    ...
    <update>
        ...
        <targetplatform name="joomla" version="3.0"/>
        ...
    </update>
</updates>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had renamed everything to the respective plugin name but still joomla wasn't finding the new copied and modified plugin that I had created.

Finally I found out that the `plugin` attribute of the XML object, needs to be the same name that of the plugin. So lets say that the new plugin name is `xxyyzz`, As shown below with the other respective changes, the plugin attribute should also be updated.

```
<files>
    <filename plugin="xxyyzz">xxyyzz.php</filename>
</files>
```